# How to simplify an expression when converting it to a string?

Tags: c#, lambda

I need to pass an expression from a WinForms client to a WebApi. I have the following expression:

```
var results = somelist.Select(p => p.Id).ToList<int>();
Expression<Func<MyObj, bool>> myexp = x => results.Contains(x.Id);
```

I then simply did:

```
var str = myexp.Body.ToString();
```

However, in this particular example, the expression body looks like this:

> value(MyApp.MyForm+<>c__DisplayClass41_0).results.Contains(x.Id)

Which obviously will not work when translating back the string to an expression server-side.

Is there a way to reduce, compile, whatever the expression in a better way? Or should I use 3rd party solutions like Remote.Linq or Serialize.Linq?

Comment: If you are using JSON.NET in both projects (WinForms and WebAPI), then you could try the solution described at the accepted answer of this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253399/serialize-expression-tree

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to do with the expression on the server side.

If you really only need a string representation you might want to implement an [ExpressionVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor). However, this may require quite some effort, depending the kind of expressions you need to support.

In case you want to convert back to a proper expression tree and execute the expression on server side, it's definitely worth the have a look at [Remote.Linq](https://github.com/6bee/Remote.Linq).